# checking if a number is divisible by 2 in an if statement

Tags: java

I am working with a piece of code that checks if a number is divisible by 2, 12 and 15.

I am working with Java for the first time, and I do not understand how to use it, and so I have come here!

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.math.*;

public class PrExMa {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //variables
    BigInteger num;
    BigInteger two, tw, fi;
    num = new BigInteger("16");
    two = new BigInteger("2");
    tw = new BigInteger("12");
    fi = new BigInteger("15");

    //calculations
    // problem is here,I am trying to do
    if (num.mod(two).equals("0")) {
        System.out.print(num);
    // with if(num % two == 0) {
    //system.out.print(num);
    //}
    }
}

}
```

Comment: do you have to use BigInteger?

Comment: @Aominè yes since I will be checking beyond 64000 unsigned int limit

Comment: That's not the limit for an `int`. Please see my answer.

Comment: oh sorry, beyond 4294967295 limit

Comment: What about `long`? `Long.MAX_VALUE` is `9_223_372_036_854_775_807`, pretty big.

Comment: I will be working with numbers that exceed 10 to the power of 17

Comment: Yeah, `long` may still have room for that. The max value is `2^63 - 1`, which is about `10^19`. If it exceeds that too, you need `BigInteger`. Just note that the performance impact of `BigInteger` is huge. So you should ask yourself if you really need it. It's totally fine if you want or need to use it, just be aware of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comparison should be written as:

```
num.mod(two).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)
```

Otherwise you'd be comparing a `BigInteger` with a `String`, which clearly are different. Also, do you really have to use `BigInteger`? isn't a plain old `long` enough? remember, the maximum value for a `long` is `2^63 - 1`, enough for your needs. In that case, the comparison is as simple as this:

```
num % 2 == 0
```

Comment: And even if `int` is not enough, `long` exists too. `BigInteger` should only be considered when values exceed the range of both. The negative performance impact of `BigInteger` is huge (obviously).

Comment: I know that BigInteger isn't the best choice, but I need to work with them