# how to create a Java code to check multiple question

Tags: java

How Write one complete Java program to test whether a number entered by user is;
i)  positive or negative,
ii) multiplication of two or not,
iii)multiplication of three or not.
iv) multiplication of four or not, and
v)  multiplication of ten or not.

**Tried so far**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class selection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number:");
        n = s.nextInt();
        if (n > 0) {
            System.out.println("The number " + n + " is Positive");
        } else if (n < 0) {
            System.out.println("The number " + n + " is Negative");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The number " + n + " neither Positive nor Negative ");
        }
    }
}
```

```
Output example
Enter a number >>
15
The number is positive.
The number is not a multiplication of 2.
The number is a multiplication of 3.
The number is a multiplication of 5.
The number is not a multiplication of 10.
```

Comment: I already know how to check the num is +ve or -ve, but i don't know how to code the others question in one java file

Comment: what have you tied yet?

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

public class selection 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int n;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number:");
        n = s.nextInt();
        if(n > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("The number "+n+" is Positive");
        }
        else if(n < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("The number "+n+" is Negative");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The number "+n+" neither Positive nor Negative ");
        }
    }
}

Comment: code that i already tried for -ve and +ve number

Comment: Plz add you code in question.

Comment: @Nur  No one from StackOverflow will teach you how to write code or will provide you ready made code as your requirement, show us your efforts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [checking if a number is divisible by 2 in an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49459808/checking-if-a-number-is-divisible-by-2-in-an-if-statement)

Comment: You need to repeat if else statement with condition for each number that you want to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number, which is a multiple of n, shall be zero when divided by n. And zero is divided by no matter what the value, the rest is zero. Therefore, if the number you received is not zero but divided by 2, 3, 4, and 10, program will print the number as multiple.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;


public class selection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number:");
        n = s.nextInt();
        if (n > 0) {
            System.out.println("The number " + n + " is Positive");
        } else if (n < 0) {
            System.out.println("The number " + n + " is Negative");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The number " + n + " neither Positive nor Negative ");
        }

        if(n%2==0 && n!=0){
            System.out.println("The number " + n + " is Multiplication of two");
        }
        if(n%3==0 && n!=0){
            System.out.println("The number " + n + " is Multiplication of three");
        }
        if(n%4==0 && n!=0){
            System.out.println("The number " + n + " is Multiplication of four");
        }
        if(n%10==0 && n!=0){
            System.out.println("The number " + n + " is Multiplication of ten");
        }

        if(n%2!=0 && n%3!=0 && n%4 !=0 && n%10!=0 || n==0){
            System.out.println("The number " + n + " is not a multiple of 2 and 3 and 4 and 10");
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of way to do, simplest one would be create separate method to perform separate test like below:

```
public boolean isPositive(int num){//your logic}

public boolean ismulitplicationOf2(int num){//your logic}
public boolean ismulitplicationOf4(int num){//your logic}

etc
```

And from your method you can call these method like:

```
public boolean checkValidation(int num){
    boolean result = isPositive(num);
    // do what you want to do with result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is, Create a `StringBuilder`, and in every if statement of yours, if it satisfies your condition, append that particular word in your `StringBuilder`. You can now do multiple different if statements and for every if condition that it satisfies, append that to your StringBuilder. 
For Example,

```
if(checkEven()){
    stringBuilder.append("Even");
}
if(checkPositive()){
    stringBuilder.append("Positive");
}
System.out.println(stringBuilder);
```

This way, you won't have to use `else` more than once for every condition of yours.

Comment: It would be easier to just make it like: System.out.println(checkEven(i) ? (i + " is even") : (i + " is odd"); and so on.